# Is there any WebSocket Message Listener for JavaSE?

Tags: java, websocket, listener

I want to write simple online organizer. It'll work on WebSockets. Is there any library that allows to use method like onMessage? I mean without code like

```
is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(responseLine);
}
```

Something with listener that will start execution on message input event.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets are not for SE, but for JavaEE.

According to [JSR-356](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html) there is annotation type `OnMessage` which is used in server and client endpoints declaration and it is included into javax.websocket-api. If you use this annotation above the method, then when message is coming, this method will be invoked.

To learn more about how to implement this read [JSR-356](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html) text and [this](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api) example.